# Set-Cookie header not forwarded by nginx to the client

Tags: authentication, nginx, authorization, webapi

I have the following configuration

```
    Client(Browser) ---> Nginx ——————> Auth backend
                            |
                             ————————> Protected Backend
```

When the browser hits Nginx for `Protected Backend`, it is directed to the Identity Provider (Azure Active Directory). The IDP then provides an authorization code in response, which the browser subsequently sends to Nginx. Nginx forwards this to the `Auth Backend`, where it is exchanged for a token. The Auth Backend responds with an access token setting it in the `Set-Cookie` header. However, Nginx omits this header when sending the response back to the client. How should I tell Nginx not to omit this header?

Nginx conf

```
upstream auth_pool {
    least_conn;
    server localhost:7771;
    server localhost:7772;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    resolver 10.0.0.6:8600;
    set $domain service.eastus-1.consul;

    error_page 401 = @error401;

    client_header_buffer_size 32k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
    proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials';
    proxy_hide_header 'Cache-Control';
    proxy_hide_header 'Pragma';
    proxy_hide_header 'Expires';

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0' always;
    add_header 'Pragma' 'no-cache' always;
    add_header 'Expires' '0' always;
    expires -1;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    if_modified_since off;

    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    location / {
       auth_request /auth_backend;
       auth_request_set $x_myorg_user $upstream_http_x_myorg_user;
       auth_request_set $backend_status "500";

       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Myorg-User $x_myorg_user;
       proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
       proxy_redirect off;

       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   }

   location /auth_backend {
       internal;
       proxy_set_header X-Myorg-Original-Uri $request_uri;
       proxy_set_header Content-Length 0;
       proxy_pass_request_body off;
       proxy_pass http://auth_pool;
   }

   location @error401 {
        return 302 https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx-xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxx-xxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=openid;      
   }
```